# android: animating a drawable gets cropped, bounds not resized

Tags: android, animation

I'm  trying to animate a PNG, applying a scale transformation. All works as expected for shrink operations, but when i try and grow the image it gets cropped by the bounds of the original View.

How can reset the bounds? Can someone give me an example of how to do this?

my set xml looks like:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                                                 
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"    
   <scale                                                                                                                      
    android:fromXScale="1.0"                                                                                               
    android:fromYScale="1.0"                                                                                               
    android:toXScale="2.2"                                                                                                 
    android:toYScale="2.2"                                                                                                                                                                                          
    android:duration="1000"></scale>         
 </set>
```

main.xml contains a simple ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                                         

<RelativeLayout                                                                                                                
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                                                 
android:id="@+id/anim"                                                                                                
android:orientation="vertical"                                                                                             
android:layout_width="fill_parent"                                                                                         
android:layout_height="fill_parent">                                                                                       

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"                                                                                     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"                                                                                     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                   
    android:src="@drawable/image1"/>                          

<.RelativeLayout>
```

and the code is along the lines of

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);                                                                        
myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.drawable.anim);                                                     

img.startAnimation(myanim);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` on the ImageView.

Comment: i'd forgotten about this question!